# jquery data table server side paging

Tags: jquery, api, datatables

hi we using jquery data table ,
Till now we able to do api call and load the data .
My server side code -

```
   string headers = "\"total\": \"" + totalPages + "\", \"columnNames\": \"" + columnNames + "\", \"page\": \"" + page + "\", \"records\": \"" + totalrows + "\"";


                        responsetoken.content = functions.Serialize(ldData).Insert(1, headers + ", ");
```

and my client side code -

```
   $.ajax({
                url: 'staticreport',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                     startDate: that.startDate, endDate: that.endDate
                }),
                cache: false,
                datatype: "json",
                type: "PUT",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.StaticReportList != null) {

                      var columns = [];
                        var colName = data.columnNames.split(',');
                        console.log(colName);
                        for (var i in colName) {
                            columns.push({ data: colName[i], title: colName[i] });
                        }
                        console.log(columns);
                        console.log(columns.data);
                        $('#grid').DataTable({
                            data: data.StaticReportList,
                            columns: columns
                        });
                    }
                    that.mainView.ajaxDecrement();
                }
            });
```

i want to put paging in datatable which will call api after every next click and get next set of record , at time i only bringing 100 record and also count of total record to create the paging .

this is how my object looks
[image]

how i can apply server side paging in datatable ?

Answer (score 0):

The ajax page should be the page that is carving up the data. If you monitor your requests and responses, if the user clicks page "3" for instance, the get URL or post parameters will contain &iDisplaystart and &iDisplaylength

If you are displaying 50 records at a time, &iDisplaylength will be 50.

Ff the user clicks "3", &iDisplaystart will be 100
(Page 0 starts at 0, Page 1 at 50, page 2 at 100, page 3 ...)

Your ajax page must be able to read the request variables and contain logic to send back 50 records (read from the request variables), starting at record 100 (read from the request variables). Also included in the URL are the column sort order, and filter value if being used.

The start of your json response should be something like

```
{ "iTotalRecords":  # of total records in your data set ,
"iTotalDisplayRecords":  # of total records that match the filter or search value,
"data": [
... your jSON data starting at record 100, and running for 50 records
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for datatables server side processing https://datatables.net/manual/server-side. I think you should take the size of the records based on the dropdown and the paging. You can get the `length`(used for db limit) and `start` (used for offset) parameter sent to your server.

Datatables always send its parameters to your server, you can check it by looking into `network` tab in your browser development tool, or to the documentation. To add additional parameters for your query, you can add method `data` to your ajax request as shown below which accept the original parameters of Datatables.

```
          $("#table").DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: 'staticreport',
                    data: function (d) {
                        d.startDate = $("#startDate").val();
                        d.endDate = $("#endDate").val();
                    }
                }
           });
```

Hope this can help.